# Parsing text from CMemFile line by line

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have got a huge text file loaded into a `CMemFile` object and would like to parse it line by line (separated by newline chars).
Originally it is a zip file on disk, and I unzip it into memory to parse it, therefore the CMemFile.

One working way to read line by line is this (m_file is a smart pointer to a `CMemFile`):

```
    CArchive archive(m_file.get(), CArchive::load);

    CString line;

    while(archive.ReadString(line))
    {
        ProcessLine(string(line));
    }
```

Since it takes a lot of time, I tried to write my own routine:

```
    const UINT READSIZE = 1024;
    const char NEWLINE = '\n';
    char readBuffer[READSIZE];
    UINT bytesRead = 0;
    char *posNewline = NULL;

    const char* itEnd = readBuffer + READSIZE;
    ULONGLONG currentPosition = 0;
    ULONGLONG newlinePositionInBuffer = 0;

    do
    {
        currentPosition = m_file->GetPosition();

        bytesRead = m_file->Read(&readBuffer, READSIZE);        

        if(bytesRead == 0) break; // EOF

        posNewline = std::find(readBuffer, readBuffer + bytesRead, NEWLINE);

        if(posNewline != itEnd)
        {
            // found newline
            ProcessLine(string(readBuffer, posNewline));
            newlinePositionInBuffer = posNewline - readBuffer + 1; // +1 to skip \r
            m_file->Seek(currentPosition + newlinePositionInBuffer, CFile::begin);
        }
    } while(true);
```

Measuring the performance showed both methods take about the same time...

**Can you think of any performance improvements or a faster way to do the parsing?**

Thanks for any advice

Comment: How big is "huge"? How long are the lines? How long is "a lot of time"? I mean, maybe you are already doing it as fast as you can. Also, I imagine the "speed test" is done in release mode, isn't it? And finally, what does `ProcessLine()` do? Maybe there are lots of memory allocations or something else that's taking too much time.

Comment: @MikMik: Yes, it is difficult to judge whether my solution is already good or not. To answer a few of your questions: uncompressed files are about 100 MB, line length upto 250 chars, tested in release mode and optimized for speed. ProcessLine is an empty function. Right now it takes about 1 second/file to parse.

Comment: Often there are completely different solutions to reach your goal. Thats why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a profiler showed that 75 % of process time was wasted in this line of code:

```
 ProcessLine(string(readBuffer, posNewline));
```

Mainly the creation of the temporary string caused a big overhead (many allocs). The ProcessLine function itself contains no code. By changing the declaration from:

```
void ProcessLine(const std::string &);
```

to:

```
inline void ProcessLine(const char*, const char*);
```

process time used was reduced by a factor of five.

Answer (score 3):

A few notes and comments that may be useful:

- Profiling is the only way for sure to know what the code is doing and how long it takes. Often the bottleneck is not obvious from the code itself. One basic method would be to time the loading, the uncompressing, and the parsing individually.
- The actual loading of the file from disk, and in your case the uncompressing, may actually take significantly more time than the parsing, especially if your `ProcessFile()` function is a nop. If your parsing only takes 1% of the total time then you're never going to get much from trying to optimize that 1%. This is something profiling your code would tell you.
- A general way to optimize a load/parse algorithm is to look at how many times a particular byte is read/parsed. The minimum, and possibly fastest, algorithm must read and parse each byte only once. Looking at your algorithms each byte appears to be copied a half-dozen times and potentially parsed a similar number. Reducing these numbers may help reduce the overall algorithm time, although the relative gain may not be much overall.

Comment: I did measure the time for disk accesss, uncompressing and parsing  separately. So I know the bottleneck right now is the parsing (like you wrote in your first remark). Uncompressing is 5 times faster than parsing. I'll try to refactor my code and keep your last point mind. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I've written a number of various "large file" (100s of MB) binary/text parsers and it seems the performance limit of parsing is around the same speed as the disk loading (i.e., loading is 50% and parsing is 50%) depending on the complexity of the parsing. What I've done when lacking a real profiler is to create several versions of the parsing loop starting with the simplest (just look at each character and ignore it). This may tell you what part of the parsing is taking the most time.

Comment: By changing the code (see my own answer) I could improve performance and reached the 50% parsing/50% loading ratio you mentioned.

Comment: Great! Keep in mind the 50/50 ratio is just a rough guide and there's almost always a way to make things a little faster, although you'll quickly reach a point where the effort involved won't be worth the small amount of performance increase.

Answer (score 0):

You could run both the decompression and the parsing in separate threads. Each time the decompression produces some data, you should pass it to the parsing thread using a message mechanism to parse.

This allows both to run in parallel, and also result in a smaller memory overhead since you work in blocks rather than the entire decompressed file (which would result in less page faults and swaps to virtual memory).

Comment: Each parser is running in its own thread limited only by available physical memory and cores. I'm focusing the performance improvements to the parsing itself now. Since I use an external library I have only access to the complete unzipped file in memory and can't do it chunk by chunk.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that you are reading in too much and reseeking to new line.

If you file was

```
   foo
   bar
   etc
```

Say 10 bytes average on a line. You will read 10 lines...and read the 9 lines again.

Comment: Hmm, but I think reading & seeking are only pointer arithmetics. I mean, since I am operating on memory only, a seek should be very fast and reading just the same.

Comment: Reading in this case involves copying a buffer several times of up to 1024 bytes for each line. If you have lines much shorter than 1024 bytes you will end up copying a large amount of data you never use each time. It is this copying that will affect your performance.